# Json.Net messes up timezones for DateTimeOffset when serializing

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, json.net, datetimeoffset

I have looked at a lot of related questions but none of them seem to be working for me.

I'm trying to serialize everything in UTC. Here's my code:

```
class Class1
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Class2 foo = new Class2();
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
        }));

        Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public DateTimeOffset time = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(14663484000000000));

    public DateTimeOffset time2 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(14663484000000000);

    public DateTime time3 = new DateTime(14663484000000000);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
{
    "time": "2016-06-19T08:00:00-07:00",
    "time2": "2016-06-19T08:00:00-07:00",
    "time3": "0047-06-20T15:00:00Z"
}
```

Here's the output I'm trying to get:

```
{
    "time": "2016-06-19T15:00:00+00:00",
    "time2": "2016-06-19T15:00:00+00:00",
    "time3": "0047-06-20T15:00:00+00:00"
}
```

As you can see, the `DateTimeOffset` properties are not converted at all. The `DateTime` is, but the timezone is indicated using `Z` whereas I'm trying to use `+00:00`.

Comment: Why are you serializing your `foo` to a JSON string, then parsing the string to a `JToken` hierarchy, then re-serializing the hierarchy to a string to reproduce your problem?  If you just serialize `foo` to a string directly the time zone information is correct, yes?

Comment: @dbc I want to add some properties to the serialized JSON, but I took that part out when trying to figure this out. I still need it in the end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your code, you are doing the following:

1. Serializing an instance of `Class2` to a JSON string using specific `DateTime`-related serialization settings.
2. Deserializing to a `JToken` hierarchy *without using those settings*.
3. (Making additional modifications to the hierarchy - not shown.)
4. Serializing the `JToken` hierarchy to a final string (via `json.ToString()`) again without using those settings.

When you do, formatting settings for dates chosen in step #1 get lost.

To solve this, you need to apply the settings every time you serialize from or to a JSON string representation, since, as explained in [this documentation page](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm), JSON does not have an "official" format for dates.  Because of this, Json.NET applies heuristics for recognizing and formatting dates whenever it converts from and to a JSON string representation - which you are doing not once but thrice.

You could accomplish this by doing:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};

// Generate initial serialization
var initialString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);

// Parse back to JToken
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(initialString, settings);

// Make modifications as required
// json["foo"] = "bar";

// Generate final JSON.
var finalString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

To improve efficiency, you could use [`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject_1.htm) (or [`JObject.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject_1.htm) if you prefer) to generate the `JToken` hierarchy without needing to create and parse an initial string representation:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};

var json = JToken.FromObject(foo, JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));

// Make modifications as required
// json["foo"] = "bar";

// Generate final JSON.
var finalString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Note, however, that Json.NET will output a UTC `DateTime` in the format `"0047-06-20T15:00:00Z"` rather than `"2016-06-19T15:00:00+00:00"` for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31688701/3744182).  If you need your UTC `DateTime` properties to be serialized in `DateTimeOffset` format you might need to use a [custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635599/specifying-a-custom-datetime-format-when-serializing-with-json-net).