# How to convert proper ISO 8601 dates in C#

Tags: c#, json, date, datetime

Please help with the following date format, how can i convert this to the correct date time?

2019-10-22T02:00:00-04:00

Not sure what will be used to convert the datetime.

I just passed it to the variable because it is get from a json.

```
var parse = JObject.Parse(times);

var dateTime = parse["Date"]["overTime"];
```

It returns a 23/10/2019 2:00:00 am why is that the date on the 23 but the supposedly be on the 22. How can I return the right date and time. Please can you show me how to convert the date and explain the conversion.

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: How are you printing `dateTime`? I'm assuming `Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Value<DateTime>())`?

Comment: @Sweeper Philippine Standard Time GMT+8 but I don't want it to be converted to my timezone. I has to be the same timezone as the given date for it to be correct?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I am printing in just Console.WriteLine(dateTime);

Comment: The original timezone offset of date that is parsed *does not* become an intrinsic property of the DateTime object. You would have to separately parse the "-04:00" offset, and format the DateTime output with that offset, to ensure that the original values for date and hour come out the same.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the JSON string `times` you are trying to parse?

Comment: You need to parse your JSON with `DateParseHandling.None` or `DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset`.  see: [JToken: Get raw/original JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141787/3744182) and [Json.Net messes up timezones for DateTimeOffset when serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430768/3744182) and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `JObject.Parse` to parse the date/time, use `DateTimeOffset.Parse`. That will retain the original timezone offset, which the other form of parsing does not.

Comment: Will the DateTimeOffset.Parse affect the other data in the json file or only the dates?

Comment: This is a little more complicated than I realized when I first looked at it. I was thinking of `times` as just the string "2019-10-22T02:00:00-04:00", but now I see that it's probably a larger JSON value that includes multiple pieces of data. I think the problem is that `JObject.Parse` is automatically converting any string that looks like a date into a `DateTime` object for you, before you'd have a chance to parse it differently. You need a different parsing method, that leaves the date/time strings alone, keeping them as strings, so you can then use `DateTimeOffset.Parse` after.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by using following code below

```
JObject example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(times, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None });
```

Thanks for your answers!